# Cambiar title LoginView Django

Tags: python, django

Tengo un login.html de la siguiente manera:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="col-6 m-auto">
  <h2>Welcome! - {{ user.username }}</h2>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

En el urls.py tengo:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

De que manera podría hacer para que cuando vaya a la ruta /login. En la pestaña pueda tener como título "Iniciar Sesión" y no el nombre por defecto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay que sobrescribir el método *get_context_data* de *LoginView* para pasar variables de contexto adicionales y esto se puede hacer en el archivo *views.py*:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

class MyLoginView(LoginView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Iniciar Sesión'
        return context
```

Luego en el archivo *urls.py* se importa esta vista:

```
from .views import MyLoginView

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', MyLoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Luego se puede referenciar el título de la página en *login.html* o en la plantilla *base.html*:

```
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
```

Comment: Gracias, funcionó muy bien!

Comment: Que bien que haya funcionado